Optimizing pgvector for multi-user document storage: Best practices for indexing and partitioning
I'm using PostgreSQL with pgvector and LangChain for document storage and retrieval. My setup:

Many users, each uploading multiple documents
Documents have metadata with userId
Need to isolate user documents by user and filter by userId
Using LangChain for retrieval with filters

Current table structure:
CREATE TABLE document_vector (
    id BIGSERIAL,
    content TEXT,
    metadata JSONB,
    embedding VECTOR(1536)
);

What's the best approach to optimize for scalability and query performance?

Create a new table per user?
Add a user_id column and partition the table?
Index the metadata->>'userId'?
Another approach?

Looking for a solution that scales well and maintains good performance for vector similarity searches with user-specific filters.
Appreciate your help!
I tried implementing hash partitioning on the document_vector table based on the userId stored in the metadata JSONB field but not sure if this is the right approach.
CREATE TABLE document_vector (
    id BIGSERIAL,
    content TEXT,
    metadata JSONB,
    embedding VECTOR(1536)
) PARTITION BY HASH ((metadata->>'userId'));


Just a user_id column would be enough and you could combine this with row level security.

Thanks Frank! I'm using this with LangChain. Any ideas on how to optimize the retriever with the user_id column? Currently using:
this.vectorStore.asRetriever({
k: 3,
filter: { creator_id: creatorId }
})

Personally I would create the user_id column anyway and search only on that column, not the json content. Table partitioning is something I would only consider when expecting hundreds of millions even billions of records. Not for just a few million records. And run your own performance tests on your own production environment, that's the only thing that counts.

Thanks Frank! I went with this solution :)
